# Restrict keyboard shortcuts in TinyMCE editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce

Trying to find where to disable individual keyboard shortcuts in the jQuery version of TinyMCE editor.  Currently the list of allowable shortcuts is:

- <kbd>ctrl+z</kbd> Undo
- <kbd>ctrl+y</kbd> Redo
- <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd> Bold
- <kbd>ctrl+i</kbd> Italic
- <kbd>ctrl+u</kbd> Underline
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1-6</kbd> <kbd>h1-h6</kbd>
- <kbd>ctrl+7</kbd> p
- <kbd>ctrl+8</kbd> div
- <kbd>ctrl+9</kbd> address

Currently looking to disable all shortcuts but Undo, Redo and bold.  The rest are unnessary in our implementation due to it's unwanted formatting.

I can't seem to find the code that enables these shortcuts.  Can you point out where to find this code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disable Tested in Firefox**

This should help get you started. You might need to actually add empty shortcuts for `ctrl+u` and `ctrl+i` to disable it in other browsers, but this code has been tested to disable the actions in Firefox. Just run after the initialization of tinyMCE has run (I tested mine in Firebug):

```
for(var i in tinyMCE.editors){
  var editor = tinyMCE.editors[i];
  for(var s in editor.shortcuts){
    var shortcut = editor.shortcuts[s];
    // Remove all shortcuts except Bold (66), Redo (89), Undo (90)
    if(!(s == "ctrl,,,66" || s == "ctrl,,,89" || s == "ctrl,,,90")){
       // This completely removes the shortcuts
       delete editor.shortcuts[s];

       // You could use this instead, which just disables it, but still keeps
       // browser functionality (like CMD+U = show source in FF Mac) from interrupting the flow
       // shortcut.func = function(){  };
    }
  }
}
```

**Background**

It appears to be defined around line `2294` of `jscripts/tiny_mce/classes/Editor.js` (From the full development download).

Also, they are stored in an array in the `Editor.shortcuts` variable. They keys are setup with special chars then the keycode, like this: `ctrl,,,90`.

But from what I can tell, it seems that many browser implement their own versions of `ctrl+b`, `ctrl+i`, and `ctrl+u` and that only Gecko browsers do not:

```
// Add default shortcuts for gecko
if (isGecko) {
    t.addShortcut('ctrl+b', t.getLang('bold_desc'), 'Bold');
    t.addShortcut('ctrl+i', t.getLang('italic_desc'), 'Italic');
    t.addShortcut('ctrl+u', t.getLang('underline_desc'), 'Underline');
}
```

But if you look around there, you can see how they enable it.

Additionally, look into the [`Editor.addShortcut`](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/js/tinymce/docs/api/index.html#class_tinymce.Editor.html-addShortcut) method. You might be able to override the default behavior.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a sample on how to disable the shortcuts you didn't want.

Comment: Well, this answer doesn't leave anything to be desired. :) Withdrawing mine. +1

Comment: @Pekka well, thanks :) At first I thought the source had to be edited, but their shortcut system is actually pretty cool.

Comment: This seems to work great in Firefox but it doesn't seem to work in Safari, Chrome and IE.  Seems like I can't override the browser defaults.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: @RedWolves Is none of it working? Or are just ctrl+i and ctrl+u not working since they have a browser implementation?

Comment: Ok, so I did a bit of testing in just Safari, and I was unable to block the italic shortcut. Granted, I really don't know much about the dynamic editing modes of Safari and IE. Sorry :(

Comment: What about adding CTRL+ENTER as a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 8):

Even though this has an accepted answer, I would share what I use with tinymce4. You can simply add `editor.addShortcut('ctrl+u', "", "")` to the `init` event method within the `setup`method, which will override the added shortcut

***Example:***

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // Your options here
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on("init", function(){
            editor.addShortcut("ctrl+u", "", "");
        });
    }
})
```

You can replace any shortcut you'd like to disable with `ctrl+u` in the above code.

Comment: I did exactly this and it had no effect?  ctrl+u still underlines.

Comment: My TinyMCE verseion is 4.7.9

Comment: @levininja Use "meta+u" instead of "ctrl+u".  // "meta" maps to Command on Mac and Ctrl on PC
// "access" maps to ctrl+alt on Mac and shift+alt on PC

Answer (score 4):

OK so I was able to get this to work.  I was able to block firefox using Doug's code above to get IE to disable the key's I wanted I had to add this code after Doug's code block.

```
var $iframe = $('iframe').contents().get(0);

$($iframe).keydown(function(oEvent) {
    //italics (ctrl+i & Cmd+i [Safari doesn't allow you to test for Cmd])
    if (oEvent.keyCode == '73' && (oEvent.metaKey || oEvent.ctrlKey)){
        oEvent.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    //underline (ctrl+u & cmd+u [Safari doesn't allow you to test for cmd])
    if (oEvent.keyCode == '85' && (oEvent.metaKey || oEvent.ctrlKey)){
        oEvent.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

So basically TinyMCE dynamically loads the editor as a iFrame so I disabled the <kbd>Ctrl+u</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> from the iFrame.  I what till the iFrame is finished loading and then attach a keydown event and sniff for <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> (I also sniff <kbd>Cmd+i</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd+u</kbd> for the mac [although Safari won't let you test for cmd according to this [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html#t24).  Everything else is disabled that I need disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Example code to switch back and forth from allowing I B and U in both IE and FF.

```
var ctrlKey = false;

function removeShortcuts(){
  var e = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
  for (var s in e.shortcuts){
    if(s=="ctrl,,,73" || s=="ctrl,,,85" || s="ctrl,,,66"){
      e.shortcuts[s].func = function(){};
    }
  }
  e.onKeyUp.add(onKeyUp);
  e.onKeyDown.add(onKeyDown);
}

function resetShortcuts(){
  var e = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
  if (isGecko) {
    e.addShortcut('ctrl+b', t.getLang('bold_desc'), 'Bold');
    e.addShortcut('ctrl+i', t.getLang('italic_desc'), 'Italic');
    e.addShortcut('ctrl+u', t.getLang('underline_desc'), 'Underline');
  }
  e.onKeyUp.remove(onKeyUp);
  e.onKeyDown.remove(onKeyDown);
}


function onKeyUp(editor, event){
  if(event.keyCode == 17){
    ctrlKey = false;
  }
}

function onKeyDown(editor, event){
  if(event.keyCode == 17){
    ctrlKey = true;
  }
  if(ctrlKey && (event.keyCode == 73 || event.keyCode == 85 || event.keyCode == 66){
    tinymce.dom.Event.cancel(event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For TinyMCE v4: [List of keyboard shortcuts available within the editor body](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/keyboard-shortcuts/)

```js
tinyMCE.init({       
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on("init", function(){
            editor.shortcuts.remove('meta+u', '', ''); // "meta" maps to Command on Mac and Ctrl on PC          
        });
    }
})
```